# Manually-generated excel files versus computer-generated reports/files

Tags: microsoft-excel, cmd.exe

Why is it the data in a user-generated report (e.g., manually encoded journal entries in an excel file) are destroyed once I append or merge them using Audit Command Language or windows cmd?

Like for example, I am trying to append the contents of sales reports whose data content was manually inputted by a human being-- however, once I append them the data are destroyed. This is not the case for computer-generated reports (i.e., reports generated by SAP).

Comment: Can you add any more detail on what steps you're taking? How are you appending or merging the reports exactly?

Comment: Hi Andi, thanks for the comment. For windows cmd, I'm using copy /b *.xls consolidated.xls

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the /b parameter? I'm not familiar with it myself, but [this answer here](http://superuser.com/a/453253/151054) says `The /b flag of the copy command treats the files as binary (i.e., a raw stream of meaningless bytes)...You can merge text files with either the default text behavior or the binary switch, but pretty much any binary file will not work.`

Comment: Actually I'd learned about /b parameter just today. I'm not also familiar with that. Usually I use copy *.xls consolidated.xls in appending my files.

Comment: I don't think you can use `copy *.xls consolidated.xls` because Excel files aren't simple plain text. To my knowledge, this command only works on text/csv files. I'm surprised any consolidated file produced this way actually opens (unless your SAP reports are actually CSVs and not Excel files).

Comment: Yeah, that's my dilemma actually. But, does putting /b in your parameter work?

Comment: No, binary files don't work like that, the headers and metadata at the start of the file will be different for each file, so it's like putting random multiple bits of wallpaper next to each other and expecting the patterns to line up. They won't.

Comment: To merge Excel files in this way, you will have to first save each file as a .csv file, then merge those .csv files using `copy *.csv consolidated.csv`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense to me. It's my first time to encounter binary data and I still don't have a good grasp to its concept. Anyway, thanks for the help Andi. I guess I'll just have to use ren *.xls *.csv, will it work?

Comment: No, renaming the files won't do anything - you need to open the Excel files and save them as CSVs. You can get a macro to do this repetitive job - have a read of this: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/515067-convert-every-xls-file-in-a-folder-to-csv.html

Comment: I thought it would do the magic. Fortunately you warned me. Thanks once again. I'll just look at the excel forum. Thanks Andi.

Answer (score 1):

Excel files are [binary files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file), not plain text. Running `copy *.txt consolidated.txt` is fine but running `copy *.xls consolidated.xls` does not work because binary files are encoded so that you have to open a specific program that understands the structure of the data in the file.

One way to consolidate a folder of Excel files is simply to convert them to a plain text format (eg a csv), and consolidate those using `copy` on the command line.

You can create a macro to do this for you:

1. Create a new Excel file. Save the file in the same directory as the files you want to consolidate as a macro-enabled workbook: eg **CsvConverter.xlsm**
2. Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the Visual Basic Editor. Select **Insert** then **Module**.
3. Paste the following code into your module [(taken from here)](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/515067-convert-every-xls-file-in-a-folder-to-csv.html):

   > ```
   > Option Explicit
   >
   > Sub ConvertToCSV()
   > ' Uses code from John Walkenbach's Power Programming book
   > '
   > Dim i As Long
   > Dim NumFiles As Long
   > Dim FileName As String
   > Dim FileNames() As String
   >
   > ' Get name of first file in backlog directory
   > FileName = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xls")
   >
   > NumFiles = 1
   > ReDim Preserve FileNames(1 To NumFiles)
   > FileNames(NumFiles) = FileName
   >
   > ' Get other file names, if any
   > Do While FileName <> ""
   > FileName = Dir()
   > If FileName <> "" Then
   > NumFiles = NumFiles + 1
   > ReDim Preserve FileNames(1 To NumFiles)
   > FileNames(NumFiles) = FileName
   > End If
   > Loop
   >
   > ' Save each file as a .csv file, overwriting any existing .csv files
   > Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   > For i = 1 To UBound(FileNames)
   > If FileNames(i) <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
   > Workbooks.Open FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileNames(i)
   > ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
   > FileName:=Left(FileNames(i), Len(FileNames(i)) - 4) &
   > ".csv", _
   > FileFormat:=xlCSV
   > ActiveWorkbook.Close
   > End If
   > Next i
   > Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   >
   > End Sub
   > ```
4. [Run the macro](https://support.office.com/en-my/article/Run-an-Excel-macro-a20bf0b0-5642-4aa8-8b99-2558a6df5fe1).
5. Now on the command line, navigate to your folder and enter

   > copy *.csv consolidated.csv
6. Open **consolidated.csv** in Excel and save as a regular .xlsx worbook again to apply any formatting or other changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Andi. Really appreciate it. Very helpful for me in my data analytics work. Thanks once again.