# How to view hidden converted video file in C:\?

Tags: hard-drive

I transfered 2 video files to C:\ and combined them into a single video file like the following:
copy /b "C:\File.mp4" + "C:\File1.mp4" CombinedFile.mp4

However, the converted CombinedFile.mp4 is hidden although the file is definitely in the C:\ because when I do the same command again to combine, it gave me an option to Overwrite CombinedFile.mp4.

I have already enabled "Show hidden Files & Folders" so I could see appdata etc. but this particular video file I converted in C:\ is hidden. I'm using Windows 10 as an admin.

Comment: Are you saying that you have put user (video) files into the root directory?  (Ugh.) How did you run the `copy` command (e.g., from the Start menu / Run dialog, or from a Command Prompt)?  What do you see if you run `dir`?

Answer (score 0):

The file is most likely corrupt; the copy /b function is not meant for this purpose. Use a video combiner to do the job. 
eg http://download.cnet.com/Free-AVI-MPEG-WMV-MP4-FLV-Video-Joiner/3000-13631_4-75290164.html

More info on copy /b here: [What exactly happens when you use the 'copy /b' command?](https://superuser.com/questions/453245/what-exactly-happens-when-you-use-the-copy-b-command)

Comment: But how do you delete the hidden file? It's still there since when I did the same command, it asks me whether I intend to overwrite it.