# Use multiple files as input with ffmpeg for Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

On Linux, `cat` is a good way to combine multiple files, and pass them to `ffmpeg`, as explained in [FFMpeg open a DVD VOB chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241630/ffmpeg-open-a-dvd-vob-chain)
:

```
cat first.VOB second.VOB third.VOB | ffmpeg -i - outfile.mp4
```

This does not seem to work for Windows.

**Question: how to use multiple files as input for ffmpeg, with Windows?**

These solutions do not seem to work:

```
ffmpeg -i a.VOB b.VOB c.VOB d.VOB -c:v copy -c:a copy out.avi
ffmpeg -i a.VOB -i b.VOB -i c.VOB -i d.VOB -c:v copy -c:a copy out.avi
```

Comment: Perhaps try [concatenation from a text list of the files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the specific case of multiple .VOB input files (ex: DVD), the simplest way seems to be:

```
copy /b e:/video_ts/vts_*.vob temp.vob
```

and then encode `temp.vob` with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: This doesn't work well at all for WAV files. Something about the metadata makes it think the audio length is only that of the first WAV file the ```copy``` reads. The resulting file is a file the size of all files put together, that for some reason won't play more than the data of the first file.

Comment: @AntonioBanderéz Yes this is specific to VOB files (DVD) and doesn't work for WAV files.

Comment: What is `/b`? That seems pretty critical.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes Here is the full answer about `/b`: https://superuser.com/questions/453245/what-exactly-happens-when-you-use-the-copy-b-command

Answer (score 2):

- You can easily resolve it using this ***[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1609481/969781)*** from ***[@Gyan](https://superuser.com/users/114058/gyan)***

---

```bat
ffmpeg -i "concat:a.VOB|b.VOB|c.VOB|d.VOB|...| nn.VOB" -c:v copy -c:a copy out.avi
```

In the same way that it is done in mp4, explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1571689/969781)

```bat
>input.txt (for %x in (*.VOB)do @echo file '%~x') && ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i input.txt -c:v copy -c:a copy out.avi
```

This can be done by one line:

```bat
>input.txt (for %x in (*.VOB)do @echo file '%~x') && ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i input.txt -c:v copy -c:a copy out.avi
```

---

1. Create/Overwrite file `>input.txt` with (command block) output

   ```bat
     >input.txt (for %x in (*.VOB)do @echo file '%~x')
   ```
2. List all files with Name.Extension to output with layout `file '%~x'`

   ```bat
     >input.txt (for %x in (*.VOB)do @echo file '%~x')
   ```
3. Only if last (block command) execution `return 0` (by operator `&&`), then run `ffmpeg` command:

   ```bat
   ... && ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i input.txt -c:v copy -c:a copy out.avi
   ```

- You can also work with different drivers/folders:

  ```bat
  >"%temp%\input.txt" (for %x in ("d:\movies\last\*.VOB")do @echo file '%~x') && "c:\ffmepg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -safe 0 -f concat -i "%temp%\input.txt" -c:v copy -c:a copy "d:\movies\last\concat\out.avi"
  ```